# getting textbox value from textbox added in c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my Page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table table = this.GetTable();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);
}
private Table GetTable()
{
    var table = new Table() { Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100.00) };
    var row = new TableRow();
    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Weapon", BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold, ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black });
    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Cost(of each resource)", BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold, ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black });
    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Power Per Soliders", BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold, ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black });
    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Amount To Buy", BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold, ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black });
    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Currently Have", BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold, ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black });
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    var Weap = new List<Weapon>();

    //////////////////////////////
    Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["CurrentUser"];
    string ArmyName = dic2["UserName"].ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  WeaponN,WeaponName, Cost, AttackPAdd FROM Weapons WHERE Class=@class", sqlConnection1);
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", "Attack");
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", ArmyName);
    cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int number = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string Weapon = reader.GetString(1);
        int golda = reader.GetInt32(2);
        int attack = reader.GetInt32(3);
        var u1 = new Weapon { number = number + "", WeaponN = Weapon, Cost = golda + "", AttackPAdd = attack + "" };
        Weap.Add(u1);
    }
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "");
    foreach (Weapon u in Weap)
    {
        row = new TableRow();
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.WeaponN });
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.Cost });
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.AttackPAdd });

        var Textbox = new TextBox()
        {
            ID = u.number,
            Text = "0"
        };

        var TextBoxCell = new TableCell();
        TextBoxCell.Controls.Add(Textbox);
        row.Cells.Add(TextBoxCell);

        cmdd.Parameters["@name"].Value = u.number;
        cmdd.CommandText = "SELECT Amount FROM [Weapon-User] WHERE ArmyName=@zip and WeaponN=@name";
        int have = Convert.ToInt32(cmdd.ExecuteScalar());
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Currently Have: " + have });

        var button = new Button()
        {
            ID = "btt"+u.number,
            Text = "Buy"
        };

        button.Command += AttClick_Clicks;
        button.CommandArgument = u.number;

        var buttonCell = new TableCell();
        buttonCell.Controls.Add(button);

        row.Cells.Add(buttonCell);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

this is the onclick event where the error accours:

```
protected void AttClick_Clicks(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.CommandArgument as String;
    int num = int.Parse(name);
    Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["CurrentUser"];
    string ArmyName = dic2["UserName"].ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", ArmyName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", num);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Weapon-User] WHERE ArmyName=@zip and WeaponN=@num";
    int check = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if (check > 0)
    {
        ////////////////////// problem accures here
        TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl(name);
        string value = myTextBox.Text;
        ///////////////////
        int add = int.Parse(value);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Amount FROM [Weapon-User] WHERE ArmyName=@zip and WeaponN=@num";
        int amount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        amount = amount + add;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Cost FROM Weapons WHERE WeaponN=@num";
        int cost = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        cost = cost * add;

        int golda = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Gold FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        golda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////
        int irona = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Iron FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        irona = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////
        int wooda = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Wood FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        wooda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////

        if (golda >= cost && irona >= cost && wooda >= cost)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", amount);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Weapon-User] SET Amount=@new WHERE ArmyName=@zip and WeaponN=@num";
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gg", golda - cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ww", wooda - cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ii", irona - cost);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET Gold=@gg,Wood=@ww,Iron=@ii WHERE ArmyName=@zip";
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "You dont have enough resources";
            string url = "Shop.aspx";
            string script = "{ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += url;
            script += "'; }";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl(name);
        string value = myTextBox.Text;
        int add = int.Parse(value);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Cost FROM Weapons WHERE WeaponN=@num";
        int cost = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        cost = cost * add;

        int golda = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Gold FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        golda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////
        int irona = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Iron FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        irona = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////
        int wooda = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Wood FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
        wooda = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ///////

        if (golda >= cost && irona >= cost && wooda >= cost)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", add);
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Weapon-User] (ArmyName,WeaponN,Amount,Class) Values (@zip,@num,@new,'Attack')";
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gg", golda - cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ww", wooda - cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ii", irona - cost);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET Gold=@gg,Wood=@ww,Iron=@ii WHERE ArmyName=@zip";
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "You dont have enough resources";
            string url = "Shop.aspx";
            string script = "{ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += url;
            script += "'; }";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
        }
    }


    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

and over here i just need to add abit of details but it is mustly so i can post it, so u will be able to see the code
and over here i just need to add abit of details but it is mustly so i can post it, so u will be able to see the code

Comment: Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred: \n" + placeVariableHere + " .');</script>");               Not sure what your issue is but you can use this line of code to throw text boxes to help you debug. Place it in your aspx page...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Page.FindControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) and cast the result to proper value (method return value is `System.Web.UI.Control):

```
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

To get the value (`Text` property):

```
string value = myTextBox.Text;
```

EDIT: `FindControl` doesn't search through a hierarchy of controls; per your updated question, it appears your textboxes are within a Table control, which is within a Placeholder control. You'll need to loop through your table rows to find the correct textbox. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326(v=vs.110).aspx) for details, specifically the section titled "Locating a Control Inside a Hierarchy of Naming Containers"

Comment: well it dosent work it says to me when i run it that "object reference not set to an instance of an  object" @CoolBots

Comment: @OshriUr can you verify that e.CommandArgument.ToString() actually returns the id of the TextBox you're trying to access?

Comment: yea i have used e.CommandArgument.ToString() in another page and it works fine there.

Comment: @OshriUr ok, that's nice, but can you verify *using a breakpoint* that in this specific case you're getting the right value?

Comment: well i have no idea how to do that @CoolBots

Comment: @OshriUr Unfortunately, it's nearly impossible to help you further without you knowing at least basic debugging techniques. Look into [Visual Web Developer debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9e7w6cs(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: ok i have done it and the e.CommandArgument.ToString() dosent return the id of the textbox. @CoolBots

Comment: @OshriUr that explains the `NullReferenceException`; my answer was based on your question, which presumes the id of the TextBox is correctly passed via `e.CommandArgument`. You need to look into why the correct id is not being passed in.

Comment: problem is i have another string that i get in the begging by the e.CommandArgument
and that gets the correct value but in the 
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); it dosent

Comment: @OshriUr I see it, it's called `name`, right? Can you pass `name` to `FindControl` instead? `TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl(name);

Comment: still gets the error even when i passed the name to findcontrol @CoolBots

Comment: @OshriUr and you're sure there is in fact a TextBox in the same page that has id that's being received in `name`? Can you post ASPX portion of the code?

Comment: yes im sure http://s33.postimg.org/h6qnun3lb/asd.jpg screenshot

im entering value then pressing buy and getting the exception @CoolBots

Comment: i will edit my whole post above and paste my entire code for u to see @CoolBots

Comment: @OshriUr I updated my answer; it will help you, but you'll need to do a little reading to see how to structure the loop to find the correct textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to give the button and the textbox the same ID, that will not work in .Net.  Also, you'll have to work out what container to do the FindControl in for the value, but more or less like this..

```
var Textbox = new TextBox()
        {
            ID= "txt" + u.number,
            Text = "0"
        };

 var button = new Button()
        {
            ID = "btn" + u.number,
            Text = "Buy"
        };

if (check > 0)
    {
        //Get here the textbox value of the textbox that her id = (e.CommandArgument as string)
         var id = (sender as Button).ID.Replace("btn","txt");
         var txtBox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl(id);
         var value = txtBox.Text;
    }
```

Comment: `Page.FindControl()` returns `System.Web.UI.Control`, which doesn't have a `Text` property. You're missing a cast.

Comment: that seems to work but only one prob.
in the code : 
var value = txtBox.Value;
txtBox.Value dosent have .Value metod

Comment: @OshriUr My mistake, you have to cast it to a textbox control.  I'll edit